# Remove multiple specific named folders and ther subfolders with files with Powershell

Tags: powershell

Because I am new to powershell, I have the following situation.

I have a path d:\folder with a lot of subfolder with subfolders en files.
In this folder structure, I want to remove all folders with the name 'Temp', 'History', 'Thumbnails' and all the folders en files under that specific folder name.

I have used the following code sofar `$path = "d:\folder\" Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Force -Directory | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'temp'} | % {Remove-Item $_.FullName}`

This is only for 1 folder. I can't find the way for multiple folders?
And with this code I am getting een popup asking the delete the folder. Is there a way to do this silence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the `-Include` parameter on Get-ChildItem, which can take an array of names to 'filter' on. That way you don't need the `Where-Object` clause.

Also, there is no need for the `ForEach-Object` loop (alias `%`), because Remove-Item can work on the piped results straight away:

```
$path = 'd:\folder'
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Force -Directory -Include 'Temp', 'History', 'Thumbnails' | 
Remove-Item -Recurse -Confirm:$false -Force -WhatIf
```

By adding the `-Recurse` switch to Remove-Item, there will be no popup when a folder has child items in it.

I have added safety switch `-WhatIf` so the folders will not actually be removed. You will only see in the console what *would* happen.
Once you're happy with that, remove the `-WhatIf` switch to start deleting

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this today

Comment: @Robert Please do, and.. If you feel my answer solved your problem, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it by clicking the checkmark icon **✓** on the left. This will help others with a similar question finding it more easily.

Comment: it worked. Thank you again